# Get text between slashes based on substring

Tags: regex

I have many lines that look like this

`<HintPath>..\..\packages\Test.5.8.2\lib\net35\BLL.dll</HintPath>`

How do I search, using regex, texts between slashes that contain the substring `Test` ?

In this example, I should get `Test.5.8.2`

That's what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work:
`(?<=\\)\w*(Test)\w*(?=\\)`

Comment: `[^\\]*Test[^\\]*` - https://regex101.com/r/Su1ciI/1. If you need to check for backslashes, `(?<=\\)[^\\]*Test[^\\]*(?=\\)`

Comment: Thanks! What if it now matches 3 lines of code altogether because there happens to be Test between two slashes that are in different lines? Is there a way to match only if the 2 slashes are in the same line?

Comment: `[^\\\n]*Test[^\\\n]*` - https://regex101.com/r/Su1ciI/2

Comment: Where are you using the regex?

Comment: Using `\w` does not match a dot. You could repeat matching a dot and a digit  ``\\\w*(Test(?:\.\d+)+)\\`` https://regex101.com/r/6rbQVv/1 or use ``\\\w*(Test(?:\.\d+)+)(?=\\)`` if there can be multipe matches after each other https://regex101.com/r/tGkg2W/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[^\\\n]*Test[^\\\n]*
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Su1ciI/2).

**Details**

- `[^\\\n]*` - 0 or more chars other than `\` and newline (line feed)
- `Test` - a string `Test`
- `[^\\\n]*` - 0 or more chars other than `\` and newline.

If you need to make sure there is a `\` on the left and a `\` on the right, append `(?<=\\)` positive lookbehind at the start of the pattern and a `(?=\\)` positive lookahead at the end of the pattern:

```js
(?<=\\)[^\\\n]*Test[^\\\n]*(?=\\)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match `.5.8.2` with `\w*` but `\w` does not match a dot.

If you want to match the digits after `Test`, you could repeat 1 or more times matching a dot and 1 or more digits.

```
\\\w*(Test(?:\.\d+)+)(?=\\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\\` Match `\`
- `\w*` Match optional word characters
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `Test(?:\.\d+)+` Match Test and repeat 1 or more times matching a `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=\\)` Positive lookahead, assert a `\` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tGkg2W/1)

---

Another option is to add `\w` and the dot to a character class to match either one of them.

```
\\\w*(Test[\w.]*)(?=\\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnn01c/1)